# Monthly transactions in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL server, I want to achieve sum of transactions spent on a monthly basis for the past 6 months. Below is the query that I have written

```
with filter_6month_transactions as (
    SELECT 
        emplid, 
        format(transactiondate, 'yyyyMM') transactionmonth,
        expenseamountreimbursementcurrency,
        reimbursementcurrency,
        CAST(DATEADD(m, -6, GetDate()) AS date) report_start_date,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY format(transactiondate, 'yyyyMM')) Rank,
        er.exchangerate
    FROM Concur_Expenses_CC_HighLimit_UDA e
     LEFT join exchange_rates er
     ON e.ReimbursementCurrency = er.FromCurrency
    WHERE paymenttype LIKE '%CBCP%' 
    AND concurrecordtype IN ('Approved', 'Unassigned', 'Not approved')
    AND cast(transactiondate as date) >= CAST(DATEADD(m, -6, GetDate()) AS date) 
    AND emplid IS NOT NULL
    AND employeeemailaddress NOT LIKE 'inact_%'
),
convert_transactions_toUSD AS (
    SELECT
        emplid, 
        transactionmonth,
        (CASE 
            WHEN reimbursementcurrency = 'USD' THEN 1 * expenseamountreimbursementcurrency
            ELSE fmt.exchangerate * expenseamountreimbursementcurrency
        END) transaction_amount_usd,
        rank
        
        
    FROM filter_6month_transactions fmt
),
calc_total_spend_monthly AS (
    SELECT 
        emplid, 
        transactionmonth,
        (CASE 
            WHEN rank = 1 THEN SUM(transaction_amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid, transactionmonth )
        END) AS first_month,
        (CASE 
            WHEN rank = 2 THEN SUM(transaction_amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid, transactionmonth )
        END) AS second_month,
        (CASE 
            WHEN rank = 3 THEN SUM(transaction_amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid, transactionmonth )
        END) AS third_month,
        (CASE 
            WHEN rank = 4 THEN SUM(transaction_amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid, transactionmonth )
        END) AS fourth_month,
        (CASE 
            WHEN rank = 5 THEN SUM(transaction_amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid, transactionmonth )
        END) AS fifth_month,
        (CASE 
            WHEN rank = 6 THEN SUM(transaction_amount_usd) OVER (PARTITION BY emplid, rank )
        END) AS sixth_month
        
    FROM convert_transactions_toUSD
)

SELECT distinct * FROM calc_total_spend_monthly
```

The output received is that with duplications of rows

| emplid | transactionmonth | first_month | second_month | third_month | fourth_month | fifth_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 233737 | 202204 | NULL | 190.183636 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 233737 | 202204 | NULL | 190.183636 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 233737 | 202205 | NULL | NULL | 29.7352 | NULL | NULL |
| 233737 | 202205 | NULL | NULL | 29.7352 | NULL | NULL |
| 233737 | 202206 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51.05669000 | NULL |
| 233737 | 202206 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51.05669000 | NULL |
| 233737 | 202206 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 51.05669000 | NULL |
| 056908 | 202203 | 47898.78 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202203 | 47898.78 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202203 | 47898.78 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202203 | 47898.78 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202203 | 47898.78 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202203 | 47898.78 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202203 | 47898.78 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202204 | NULL | 12.16440000 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202205 | NULL | NULL | -81.562302 | NULL | NULL |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |
| 056908 | 202207 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 587.12828200 |

But the expected output is,

| emplid | first_month | second_month | third_month | fourth_month | fifth_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 233737 | NULL | 190.183636 | 29.7352 | 51.05669000 | NULL |
| 056908 | 47898.78 | 12.16440000 | -81.562302 | NULL | 587.12828200 |

basically pivot of all month for an employee should show in a row. What changes in the query, will  get the desired output. Please correct me.

Comment: You didn't use any `GROUP BY` at all

Comment: Pretty hard to know without seeing your base tables... but is your exchange_rates table static? Or by date?

Comment: @DaleK, exchange rate table is static.

Comment: @Squirrel, I used distinct in calc_total_spend_monthly

Comment: Distinct doesn't sum them, you need group by + sum.

Comment: Side note: `ORDER BY EOMONTH(transactiondate)` is probably significantly faster than `FORMAT`

Comment: Thanks guys, I got the solution, instead of case statement, i have to add subquery.

Answer (score 1):

As Dale has mention in comment, you need to use `GROUP BY` with `SUM()`

Change your final query to

```
SELECT emplid, 
       first_month  = sum(first_month),
       second_month = sum(second_month),
       third_month  = sum(third_month),
       fourth_month = sum(fourth_month),
       fifth_month  = sum(fifth_month),
       sixth_month  = sum(sixth_month)
FROM   calc_total_spend_monthly
group by emplid
```

Actually, your entire query may be simplified to (after removing unnecessary columns and cte)

```
with filter_6month_transactions as (
    SELECT 
        emplid, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY format(transactiondate, 'yyyyMM')) as [Rank],
        CASE WHEN reimbursementcurrency = 'USD' 
             THEN 1 * expenseamountreimbursementcurrency
             ELSE er.exchangerate * expenseamountreimbursementcurrency
             END as transaction_amount_usd
    FROM Concur_Expenses_CC_HighLimit_UDA e
     LEFT join exchange_rates er
     ON e.ReimbursementCurrency = er.FromCurrency
    WHERE paymenttype LIKE '%CBCP%' 
    AND concurrecordtype IN ('Approved', 'Unassigned', 'Not approved')
    AND cast(transactiondate as date) >= CAST(DATEADD(m, -6, GetDate()) AS date) 
    AND emplid IS NOT NULL
    AND employeeemailaddress NOT LIKE 'inact_%'
)
SELECT emplid, 
       first_month  = sum(case when [Rank] = 1 then transaction_amount_usd end),
       second_month = sum(case when [Rank] = 2 then transaction_amount_usd end),
       third_month  = sum(case when [Rank] = 3 then transaction_amount_usd end),
       fourth_month = sum(case when [Rank] = 4 then transaction_amount_usd end),
       fifth_month  = sum(case when [Rank] = 5 then transaction_amount_usd end),
       sixth_month  = sum(case when [Rank] = 6 then transaction_amount_usd end)
FROM   filter_6month_transactions
group by emplid
```

OR using the `PIVOT` operator

```
SELECT emplid, 
       first_month  = [1],
       second_month = [2],
       third_month  = [3],
       fourth_month = [4],
       fifth_month  = [5],
       sixth_month  = [6]
FROM   filter_6month_transactions
       PIVOT
       (
           sum(transaction_amount_usd)
           for [Rank] in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
       ) p
```

Comment: You mentioned it before me mate :) I was just reiterating :)

Comment: @Squirrel, Its really amazing. I got the answer with just 25lines of code.... Its making me so embarassing to see your code. Your code worked awesome without any changes. Thank you so much. I appreciate your experience.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CTE code for `calc_total_spend_monthly` with `GROUP BY emplid`

```
SELECT 
    emplid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN transaction_amount_usd ELSE 0 END) AS first_month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN transaction_amount_usd ELSE 0 END) AS second_month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 3 THEN transaction_amount_usd ELSE 0 END) AS third_month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 4 THEN transaction_amount_usd ELSE 0 END) AS fourth_month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 5 THEN transaction_amount_usd ELSE 0 END) AS fifth_month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 6 THEN transaction_amount_usd ELSE 0 END) AS sixth_month        
FROM convert_transactions_toUSD
GROUP BY
    emplid
```